# Wrap image of GMENU item

Tags: typo3, typoscript

Is it possible to wrap the image inside the link of a GMENU item?
**Current TypoScript:**

```
lib.logoFooter = COA_INT
lib.logoFooter {
    50 = HMENU
    50{
        special = directory
        special.value = #folderPID#
        1 = GMENU
        1 = GMENU
        1 {
            wrap = <ul class="GMENU-wrap">|</ul>
            NO = 1
            NO{
                wrap = <li class="GMENU-item-wrap">|</li>
                altImgResource{
                    import = uploads/media/
                    import {
                        field = media
                        listNum = 0
                    }
                    maxW = 150
                    maxH = 150

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Current Result:**

```
<ul class="GMENU-wrap">
    <li class="GMENU-item-wrap">
        <a someParams="someValues">
            ###WantToInsertSomeHTMLHere###
            <img someImageParams="someImageValues"/>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Now I can wrap the link, is it also possible to wrap the img in the link (*###WantToInsertSomeHTMLHere###*) ?

Answer (score 1):

you want to insert something inside your a-tag? Just add `ATagBeforeWrap` and `linkWrap` .

```
NO{
  wrap = <li class="GMENU-item-wrap">|</li>
  ATagBeforeWrap = 1
  linkWrap = WantToInsertSomeHTMLHere|
  altImgResource{
    import = uploads/media/
    import {
      field = media
      listNum = 0
    }
    maxW = 150
    maxH = 150
  }
}
```